# Where can I find what C++ API correspond to what llvm commands?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api

What is a general way to look at LLVM and find the corresponding calls in the C++ API?
For example, I have the logical *and* instruction which corresponds to the Language reference [here](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#add-instruction).
How can I find a corresponding C++ API reference? My general approach would be to put "llvm add instruction C++ API" into a search engine, but this isn't consistently useful.

Comment: Absolutely, but really, my question is about how to navigate development around LLVM. No, I do not expect a perfect mate, but I would like to know how I go about finding something that maps one to the other.

Comment: @Swordfish can you please give an example of such instruction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually for an `someinst` instruction there is a `SomeInstInst` class. For instance, `alloca` is implemented by `AllocaInst`.

But not for `add`, that's what confused you. Binary arithmetic and logical instructions are implemented using single class called [`BinaryOperator`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BinaryOperator.html).

Another exception is a `phi` instruction - it is implemented in the `PHINode` class. Other than that, figuring what class you need should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: As a follow-up, given a function call, say [CreateNUW](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BinaryOperator.html#af85efaaa4ecdbcac97c45c8351d826b7), is there some textual documentation for me to find out what a function does without reading the function definition's source code?

Comment: If there is no documentation in Doxygen, then no, I think. But such functions are mostly self-explanatory.